# columns are not showing when adding from "Add from existing list or site columns"

Tags: content-type, column, groups

I want to add some columns to content type from a specific column group. I click on "Add from existing list or site columns" and choose one column group. But below in the available columns list, I am not able to see all the columns that are in specific column group. The column which i want to select is not visible in available columns list? How i can see all the columns in the dropdown columns list?

Comment: Do you see all your columns when you don't select a group, i.e. you leave group set to "All Groups"?

Comment: If you look in the column gallery in the site collection in which you're working, can you see the columns you're trying to add? Are these columns that have been created in a content type hub and published, or have they been created in the local site collection?

Comment: Yes, I can see all the columns in site collection column gallary under that specific column group. All the custom columns are provisioned through Visual studio. Any idea?